# How can i develop my custom module?

Tags: magento-1.7, ce-1.7.0.2, module, custom

I am using magento 1.7.
I want to develop my own module for my site. I need to add two tables in my database. My module is to manipulate these two tables from the Admin interface as adding, editing, and deleting and in frontend viewing and doing research.
What are the major steps that I should do, I am newbie in magento and I read about the architecture of Magento and I understand.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Go through these links to learn about modules.. [link1](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/03/01/basics-creating-magento-module/), [link2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/576908/1577396) and [link3](http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/magento/magento_connect.htm).

Comment: Give this a try. It will build the code for you. http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/ultimate-modulecreator-8949.html

Answer (score 1):

Please check out [this article](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/custom_module_with_custom_database_table) on the Magento Wiki.
It covers using only one table but if you duplicate all the resource models where required it should do exactly what you want.

It creates a backend grid and edit page for database items and in the frontend a page that displays your data. For training purposes please skip the module creator and write everything yourself so you have a good understanding of what is going on in your extension.

Answer (score 0):

Some more additional resources you will find helpful [Module Creator](https://github.com/shell/Magento-Module-Creator)

Download as zip and extract to your magento root , and in your browser direct to %magentoroot%/moduleCreator

Provide the necessary name spaces , and copy to respective folder , and your ready to go.

Your can also give a try to the Online Module creator @
[Online Module creator](http://www.silksoftware.com/magento-module-creator/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create Magento admin module, this [admin module tutorial](http://www.webspeaks.in/2010/08/create-your-first-adminbackend-module.html) may help you.