# How to change Max Depth of Top Category Navigation for specific store?

Tags: admin, configuration, navigation, magento-1.4

There is an admin setting called `System -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Category Top Navigation -> Maximal Depth`, which is only available in global scope.

1. What is the reason of hiding this setting for scopes other than global?
2. How to change this setting for specific Website/Store, if I have a multisite?

*Magento ver. 1.4.2.0*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up adding a row in `core_config_data` ( duplicate of row with path =  `catalog/navigation/max_depth`, but with `scope` set to 'stores' and `scope_id` set to my store id )

Answer (score 4):

I don't know why configuration of navigation depth is setted for global. You can change settings adding `system.xml` to your local module. Add these configuration for store level of navigation depth:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <sections>
        <catalog>
            <groups>
                <navigation>
                    <fields>
                        <max_depth>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </max_depth>
                    </fields>
                </navigation>
            </groups>
        </catalog>
    </sections>
</config>
```

Clean the cache. This helps you to configure navigation depth on store level.

Comment: Follow tutorials: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/8398/how-can-i-develop-my-custom-module